# React native inlineImageLeft value

Tags: react-native

I want to know the proper value for `inlineImageLeft` prop. in react native `<TextInput>` component. Can any one help me?

I copied the image in drawable folder.

```
<TextInput
  autoCapitalize= {'words'}
  autoFocus={true}
  caretHidden = {false}
  keyboardType={'url'}
  defaultValue={'Hello!'}
  placeholder={'hello world'}
  placeholderTextColor= {'red'}
  returnKeyType = {'send'}
  secureTextEntry={true}
  selectTextOnFocus={false}
  inlineImageLeft="user"
/>
```

Comment: It is used to set the image inside a text input or textview. Works only for android. Place image inside drawables folder and give path

Comment: I copied it in resources folder but still it is not working.

Comment: I just tested it and it is working fine, please post you code and also tell which folder have you copied the image ?

Comment: can you post your code and image path

Comment: I created a drawable folder insideres folder and pasted a image in that folder say image.png

Then used it like 

                            inlineImageLeft="image"

Comment: same I did as you suggested.

Comment: Uninstall the app and run project again, I also faced the same problem and solved after installing the app again

Comment: I am working on emulator. Is it an emulator problem?

Comment: Just uninstall the previous app and re run the project, close the packager also before compiling the project again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Drawable folder inside android res directory . Copy the image say image.png in that folder. Then use in TextInput component.

inlineImageLeft="image"

If image is not showing just uninstall the previous app and rerun the project.

Answer (score 0):

From the [React Native github page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.30/docs/textinput.html):

```
<TextInput
    inlineImageLeft="ic_menu_black_24dp"
    placeholder="This has drawableLeft set"
    style={styles.singleLine}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example in UIExplorer in `react-native`. In this example the `inlineImageLeft` prop used this way:

```
<TextInput inlineImageLeft="ic_menu_black_24dp"/>
```

Example is in:

> react-native/Examples/UIExplorer/js/TextInputExample.android.js

It seems path should be relative to ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable/. Any other path does not work. Also image does not scale.

Comment: how to give size ?

Answer (score 0):

I also can't see the icon inside `TextInput`. 
Then, I try to uninstall and reinstall App.

I got the build failed error:

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > C:\Users\yusuf\git\App3\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\search.ico:
>   >     Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

Then, I changed my file type from **.ico to .png**

Image should be in the "drawable" folder.

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.modalInput}
    autoFocus ={true}
    inlineImageLeft='search'
    inlineImagePadding={5}
    placeHolder ="Search Product"
    placeholderTextColor="white"
    onChangeText={ (text) => this.setState({text})}
    value = {this.state.text}
    />
```

With the above change, it works now.